# Jest tests pass even though assertion fails

Tags: async-await, jestjs

I'm testing an async function using jest. The code within the function is in a `try catch` block with errors being caught and handled, much like the following

```
export default async () => {
    try {
        await promisesAndThat();
    } catch (e) {
        // handle errors
    }
}
```

When I run `npm test`, the async function throws an error as expected and returns the result to jest, which then complains about an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and fails on an assertion, *but* the test passes regardless. Please see below for more:

```
/home/app # npm test

> node-js-base@1.0.0 test /home/app
> jest

(node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected value to be:
"Invalid context"
Received:
"Invalid parameters"
(node:77) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:77) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PASS  function/handler.test.js
✓ Should return true with valid parameters (8ms)
✓ Should return false with invalid parameters (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.276s
Ran all test suites.
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Is there any TestBefore or TestAfter, where there is a Promise?

Comment: There is a test with a promise before it, yes.

Comment: so you have a beforeEach or afterEach as described in https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown? If a Promise rejection occurs in one of those tunctions, then the error then jest fails to show were the problem occured.